# strange python nested for loop behavior

Tags: python, loops

Can anyone explain what is happening 
when I run the below python snippet?

```
import itertools

def prob():
    testlists = itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],4)
    for itervalue in range(5,50):
        for tlist in testlists:
            print itervalue
```

My expected behavior would be for every value of itervalue from 5 to 50 to be printed to the screen multiple times (once for each list in testlists).  This is what happens if I define testlists as, for example.

```
testlists = [[1,2,3],[5,2,1],[3,2,9]]
```

What actually happens is that only the first itervalue is printed to output (5 gets printed out hundreds of times).  EX:

```
5
5
5
#and so on
```

What exactly is happening here?  I'm new to python and dynamic languages in general. Thanks for any help.

I tested this on computers running python 2.6.6 and 2.7.3.

Comment: Maybe you should be printing `tlist` instead. Look at your loop

Comment: You have the loops the wrong way round.

Comment: no this is intentional behavior.  My actual problem is bigger, and I need access to itervalue.  The fact remains that itervalue is NOT getting increased within the nested loop, which confuses me.  Thanks though!

Comment: I realize that the loops are not useful as written.  But I can't figure out why the program is not doing what I expect.

Comment: Once you run through `testlists` once, the iterator is done. You can't run through an iterator more than once.

Comment: As Blender said `itertools.combinations` returns an iterator, so you can't use it more than once. Try converting it to a list or tuple first : `testlists = list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],4))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
 the problem is that your *testlists* can be looped only once, as it is not a list/tuple but a generator. Therefore your internal loop runs only once.

Change your code for:

```
import itertools

def prob():
    testlists = list(itertools.combinations([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0],4))
    for itervalue in range(5,50):
        for tlist in testlists:
            print itervalue
```

Comment: @vancan1ty The problem is that your *testlists* is a generator but not a list. Check my updated answer. The question is really good :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks Maksym, that makes sense ^.  Haven't used generators much yet -- will know what to look for next time.